# jquery UI dialog confirmation not confirming

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have this link on my page:

```
<a href='/Admin/Users/Delete/123' class='confirm'>Delete</a>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete this user?">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        This item will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?
    </p>
</div>
```

And this javascript:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Delete": function () {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr("href"); ;
         },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("a.confirm").click(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
});
```

The dialog opens like I should when I click the link. The only problem is that it doesn't wait for me to confirm or cancel, the dialog just pops up and it redirects to the url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have the wrong `this` in your `delete` handler.

Comment: @SLaks - actually, that's correct: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation (presumably the callback is called with `apply`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a.confirm").click(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

You need to prevent the default action from occurring by returning false.

Comment: Wow, that's mad - almost identical wording (your answer didn't appear until I'd submitted mine).

Comment: I'll delete my answer, but something I've learned recently is that it's better to use `e.preventDefault()` rather than `return false`, because you may want the `click` event to carry on bubbling, even if you don't want the default action to occur.

Comment: Haha, wow. Thanks. I actually chose `return false;` because I usually don't want the event bubbling.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Also I've had problems with doing stuff like that when the function-call takes to long and the browser just do the default thing (in this case navigate to the address), the solution to that problem is to put preventDefault at the top of the function, which I've made good practice of. Just a hint though, as the code you posted should work too.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's better that way. I know a lot of people just use `return false` because that's all they know, so it's always worth pointing it out!

Comment: @Skilldrick Agreed. @Alxandr Good tip, I haven't had that come up before, but I'll probably do that from now on just in case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return false from your anchor's click event else the page will be loaded with the href URl.
Try this:

```
$("a.confirm").click(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```